# JavaScript project structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, convention

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I want to create a project. I've read online that by using `npm init` a *package.json* file is created. By using `npm install --save` or `npm install --save--dev` I can install packages and they will be added to that *package.json* file.

- I used `npm install jquery --save` to be able to use jQuery. But how can I include jQuery into my JavaScript file?
- When I have a project folder with a src-folder and html-folder. Do I have to put the *package.json* file in the src-folder or in the project folder?
- Are there any other conventions I should know about?

Comment: Jquery is useful for DOM operations. Node is mainly for the backend, if you want to use jquery in the frontend I recommend you use Bower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can but I suggest for you to see http://yeoman.io

A little "architect" who can to help you to start your studies about projects structures.

http://yeoman.io/generators/

Comment: If I use the generic 'webapp-generator', can I then afterwards use other generators (like 'jquery-generator') to add functionality?

Comment: So you can see the generators list here http://yeoman.io/generators  , but if you want just add jquery or others libraries in your project. I suggest the bower. http://bower.io/

Comment: Try to find about the "bowerJS, gruntJS and yoemanJS". They can help you to do a good optimized project.

Comment: I think yeoman is a good answer, but since op is a beginner there is more to digest, such as grunt, installing yo, generators, etc. I would actually recommend @JN11 start with some beginner tutorials with basic html and static sites before even getting into node.

Comment: @vcrzy I've configured the standard Yeamon webapp, but I'm just trying to understand what all the Grunt tasks are for. I know what the purpose of Bower and Bootstrap and jQuery is and where I can add new HTML-files and so on. Also, how can I configure it to run on a server (and not localhost)?

Comment: If I understood, you need a remote server likes www.digitalocean.com . There you can install the node and run your goods,to remotly access... It was that?

Comment: Yes, I have a server provided by my university and want to run my web-application from there.

Comment: Fine, just configure your project server to run there. If you need more help, you can call me here. hugs.

Comment: Do I have to configure it in the Gruntfile?

Comment: How can we talk in the stackoverflow chat? I'm new here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64540/discussion-between-jn11-and-vcrzy).

Answer (score 1):

I created a project for you that has Node.js, Express and jQuery all set up:

https://github.com/timothyerwin/node-express-jquery-boiler

You should be able to start it with:

`npm install`
`npm start`
`http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Can you explain the structure of this project to me? Where do I put my own HTML and JavaScript files? Which files are client files and which are server files? Can I integrate Bootstrap in this project?

Comment: the client files are under `public` and the rest are basically server files. I updated the code to include bootstrap along with a `bootstrap.html` example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nodejs is only used to **make custom builds of jquery**, more info here:

[How to build your own jquery (Github)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery)

You dont need to put any json file in your proyect, you can learn how to build Jquery in a different directory here:

[Building to a different directory (Github)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#building-to-a-different-directory)

Note: Jquery is a client-side library not a sever side module.